# Синхронизация глобальной переменной между потоками

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, synchronized

Есть статичная переменная к которую читают и записывают разные потоки:

```
public static volatile int iDrvMot0OutPort;

if ((iDrvMot0OutPort & 0x0001) == 0x0001) {
    iDrvMot0OutPort &= ~0x0001;
    iDrvMot0OutPort |= 0x0400;
}
```

Как сделать запись потокобезопасной?

Хотел сделать через AtomicInteger:

```
public static AtomicInteger iDrvMot0OutPort;

if ((iDrvMot0OutPort.get() & 0x0001) == 0x0001) {
    iDrvMot0OutPort.set(iDrvMot0OutPort.get() & ~0x0001);
    iDrvMot0OutPort.set(iDrvMot0OutPort.get() | 0x0400);
}
```

Но после get() любой поток может захватить переменную и "испортить".
Использовать Lock - затратно по времени, хотя как крайний вариант пойдет.
Использование блока synchronized требует ввода еще глобального объекта.
В общем ищу что-то:

```
public synchronized static volatile int iDrvMot0OutPort;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно готовите [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

```
iDrvMot0OutPort.updateAndGet(v -> {
    if ((v & 0x0001) == 0x0001) {
        v &= ~0x0001;
        v |= 0x0400;
    }
    return v;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение. Но как быть если проект под Android 4.4 (API label 19) ?

Comment: Передавать вместо лямбды экземпляр `IntUnaryOperator`.

Comment: так updateAndGet и IntUnaryOperator - Added in API level 24

Comment: Тогда только синхронизация.